# Over (order by ) windowing function not working

Tags: sql

i am running a following Query

```
SELECT fdPaymentDate,
   COUNT(fnAccNo ) as count,
   SUM(COUNT(fnAccNo )) OVER (ORDER BY fdPaymentDate) as running_total
FROM tblPaymentDetail
GROUP BY fdPaymentDate
ORDER BY fdPaymentDate;
```

it gives error 
Incorrect syntax near 'order'.

Please help me for this problem

Comment: What rdbms are you working with?

Comment: This feature is introduced in Sql Server 2012. Don't expect it to work in anything less than that

Comment: AFAIK, `SUM(COUNT(whatever))` is also not supported in SQL server.

Comment: @ZoharPeled - It is allowed http://rextester.com/live/FPSPU8551

Comment: @Prdp i am using SQL SERVER 2008. is there any way to do   this  in SQL SERVER 2008.

Comment: Please give expected result set

Comment: @Prdp Yes, I see what you mean. but that's only allowed in window functions, right?